# Footer data is getting invisible after decreasing the size of the page

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, footer

In the react-bootstrap page, I have added the footer container which created 3 containers that store the information, but when decrease the size of the page the data is getting invisible directly, the data is not shown on the footer because of the div length issue.

What I need is when page size is getting decreased the footer data should not be invisible directly, it should be based on div size, given information should be hidden based on div size like Google earth footer data.

Example :
If my footer data is "Welcome to the React-Bootstrap world"
If the page size is decreased then word should be look like "Welcome to the..."

Below is the code

```
<Container fluid className='container-footer'>
    <Row>
        <Col md={6}>Loading</Col>
        <Col md={6}>
            <div className="footer-controller">
                <a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JavaScript library for interactive maps" style={{color:'#fff'}}>
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="8">
                        <path fill="#4C7BE1" d="M0 0h12v4H0z"></path>
                        <path fill="#FFD500" d="M0 4h12v3H0z"></path>
                        <path fill="#E0BC00" d="M0 7h12v1H0z"></path>
                    </svg> Leaflet</a>
                <span aria-hidden="true">|</span>  Welcome to the React-Bootstrap world
            </div>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
```

Css

```
.container-footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 19px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 100;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.footer-controller {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: You should share some of your code

Comment: @Arnau I have updated the code, you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
.container-footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 59px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 100;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;

.footer-controller {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

you can see it in action here https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-voice-7fdjsw?file=/src/styles.css:278-370

but I just tested without bootstrap

Anyway in short, you have to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`